# What Fields in Active Directory Are Not Only Unique, But Also Immutable (ADFS)

Tags: active-directory, adfs

I've been looking for a way to identify a user in Active Directory without fail. I found this [article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/openspecification/2009/07/10/understanding-unique-attributes-in-active-directory/) which explains which fields are unique. It's a good starting point, but doesn't identify which fields are non-mutable. Further google queries result in AzureAD results on `immutableId`, which is what I want, but for regular AD. The case I'm trying to prevent is I use `sAMAccountName` (which is unique) to identify a user, but an admin decides to change the `sAMAccountName` for some reason (perhaps for uniformity) and I identify the same old user (with now a new `sAMAccountName` as a new user.

A few contenders from the article:

- DN
- UPN
- sAMAccountName
- ObjectGUID

Is there anything I'm missing? Is there an `immutableId` equivalent in pure AD (Not AzureAD)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you likely want is [`objectGUID`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-objectguid). As "GUID" suggests, it is "globally unique". It doesn't change, even when the account is moved to another domain.

There is also [`objectSid`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-objectsid) (SID = Security Identifier), which is what Windows permissions use (the SID is stored in the permissions). It is also globally unique, but part of the SID is the SID of the domain. So if the account is moved to another AD domain, a new SID is generated on that domain, and the old `objectSid` is put in the [`sIDHistory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-sidhistory) of the new account.

There is some extra reading about that here: [Security identifiers and globally unique identifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/access-control/security-identifiers#security-identifiers-and-globally-unique-identifiers)

The `distinguishedName` changes whenever the account is renamed or moved to a new OU.

As you noted, both `userPrincipalName` and `sAMAccountName` can change too.